# Driving with a revoked license

Tags: driving, tennessee

In the state on Tennessee am I required to have a valid driver's license to drive myself around?

Comment: Yes, you are.  Why would you think otherwise?

Comment: Driving for the military or driving an agricultural tractor between fields often get exceptions, but I doubt either would be called driving yourself around.

Answer (score 3):

[Tennessee Code 55-50-301 (a) (1)](http://codes.findlaw.com/tn/title-55-motor-and-other-vehicles/tn-code-sect-55-50-301.html):

> No person, except those expressly exempted in this section, shall drive any motor vehicle upon a highway in this state unless the person has a valid driver license under this chapter for the type or class of vehicle being driven;

Moreover, under [55-50-504 (a) (1)](http://codes.findlaw.com/tn/title-55-motor-and-other-vehicles/tn-code-sect-55-50-504.html), it is a crime to drive with a revoked license:

> A person who drives a motor vehicle within the entire width between the boundary lines of every way publicly maintained that is open to the use of the public for purposes of vehicular travel, or the premises of any shopping center, manufactured housing complex or apartment house complex or any other premises frequented by the public at large at a time when the person's privilege to do so is cancelled, suspended, or revoked commits a Class B misdemeanor.